# Etiqueta div y su atributo class

Tags: html, primefaces

¿Que significa añadir mas referencias dentro del atributo `class` de la etiqueta `div` ?

Tengo esto en mi archivo `css`

```
.ui-g-1 {
  width: 8.3333%;
}

.ui-g-2 {
  width: 16.6667%;
}

.ui-g-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.ui-g-4 {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.ui-g-5 {
  width: 41.6667%;
}

.ui-g-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Entonces dentro del atributo `class` puedo referenciar a cualquiera de ellos, mi pregunta ¿Qué modifica si agrego mas referencias? ¿Afecta a la izquierda, derecha arriba o abajo?

```
<div class="ui-g-3 ui-g-10 ui-g-1">
  <p:outputLabel value="Ejemplo" class="negrita"/>
</div>
```

Esto es lo que renderiza.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto cuando inspecciono la página

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y bienvenid@ a SO. La comunidad tiene ciertas normas para publicar preguntas. Te sugiero hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) (_el enlace está en el footer_) para que conozcas estas normas, luego edita tu pregunta poniendo el código en formato texto en lugar de usar imágenes por ejemplo y así evitas que te la cierren.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo, estás agregando varias referencias de la misma propiedad `width`. Por lo tanto, se estarían "sumando" los procentajes del ancho en el elemento `div`.

Esto no afecta en una dirección específica al elemento, sino mas bien aumenta su tamaño de manera horizontal, *derecha e izquierda simultáneamente, si lo quieres poner en términos de dirección*.

Lo que significa que a mayor cantidad de referencias agregadas en el atributo `class`, mas ancho va a ser el elemento `div`.

Por ejemplo:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
.ui-g-1 {
  width: 8.3333%;
}

.ui-g-2 {
  width: 16.6667%;
}

.ui-g-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.ui-g-4 {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.ui-g-5 {
  width: 41.6667%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-g-1 ui-g-3">
  <p>EJEMPLO</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="ui-g-1 ui-g-3 ui-g-5">
  <p>EJEMPLO</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="ui-g-2 ui-g-3 ui-g-4">
  <p>EJEMPLO</p>
</div>
```

Si no es clara la explicación, deja un comentario.